# How can I assing a certain array member to a member variable of a class which is also an array

Tags: c#, arrays, class

Sorry for the confusing title! I'll try to simplify it.
I have a class which I created to immitate the behavior of typedef in C/C++. I want to use a user defined type `Pixel` for all pixel values because today it is `byte` but in the future it can be a `uint16`. 
I am scanning all the places that pixels are handled and there are operations like this:

```
private void ParseImageData()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[imageSize];

    foreach (byte[] packet in ImagePackets)// private readonly List<byte[]> ImagePackets;
    {
        byte[] datapacket = SomeFunction(packet);// private byte[] SomeFunction(byte[] imagePacket)
        datapacket.CopyTo(data, count);
        count += PACKET_SIZE;
    }
    
    // do something with Pixel type
}
```

So this code block basically transfer data that is stored in a list to a array. The problematic part is the `CopyTo` line. If I convert `data` from `byte[]` to `Pixel[]`, it will try to copy bytes to Pixels. Which is not right. I know that this doesn't make sense but If I could write something like this `datapacket.CopyTo((pixel.Value)[], count)` my problems would be solved!. 
So now I added a for loop to copy the content manually. But I hated this method and I am not sure it will work if `Pixel.Value` will be something other than `byte`. I am also considering to add a new class for pixel arrays but I don't think that is an elegnat way to do it either. Here is my (hopefully)temporary solution:

```
private void ParseImageData()
{
    Pixel[] pixels = new Pixel[imageSize];

    foreach (byte[] packet in ImagePackets)
    {
        byte[] datapacket = SomeFunction(packet);
        
        for(int i = 0; i< PACKET_SIZE; i++,count++)
        {
            pixels[i].Value = datapacket[i];
        }
    }
    // do something with Pixel type
}
```

Here is the Pixel class and a potantial Pixel array class:

```
public class Pixel
{
    public Pixel(byte val)
    {
        this.Value = val;
    }
    public byte Value { get; set; }
}

public class PixelArr
{
    public PixelArr(ushort size)
    {
        this.Value = new byte[size];
    }
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* want a `Pixel` class; an object per pixel would be catastrophic. Honestly, I *think* you should just eat the `byte` => `ushort` conversion later if you need to, but if you *really really* want a `Pixel` struct that is basically a fancy `byte`, you could do something like:

```cs
public readonly struct Pixel // readonly *very* deliberate here
{
    private readonly byte _value;
    public Pixel(byte value) => _value = value;
    public byte Value => _value;
    // TODO: add equality/hash/tostring, etc
    // TODO: operators?
}
```

Now, you can't use variance with value-type arrays, but: you *can* use reinterpret operations on *spans*. If you want to go that route: `MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, Pixel>` (or the other way around) may help. It the two types are of different sizes, the output span will have a different length than the input, accordingly. But: if you're changing from `byte` to `ushort`, that then prompts questions about "endianness" and which CPUs you need this to work on!

However, and I can't emphasize this enough: I think you'd be better off just eating the change to `ushort` later and dealing with raw values.

Comment: I don't want to have this class though, what I really want is just to have  a `typedef byte pixel` so that I can easily change the byte to something else in the future. I cannot foresee what would the next type be and it would be really hard in the future to change everything because it used in everywhere in the code. I have time now to handle this properly(?).

Comment: @İpek C# simply doesn't have `typedef`, and generics don't work that way, so... that isn't going to work the same

Comment: Hmm okay, is there a best practice for this kind of applications then? The only options are either class/struct or replacing all the types manually in a project when it is necessary?

Comment: @İpek there is "using alias", but that is per file